# Why was Abel a "keeper of flocks"?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 4:2 says that Abel was a "keeper of flocks" while Cain was a "tiller of the ground". This is only a few verses after Genesis 3:23 where God sent man out "to cultivate the ground from which he was taken". So, it seems that Abel was disobedient to the command given in Genesis 3:23 (and also in Genesis 3:17). Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The commands you point are regards to food.

> Gen 2:17 "Then to Adam He said, "Because you have heeded the voice of
>   your wife, and have eaten from the tree of which I commanded you,
>   saying,`You shall not eat of it': "Cursed is the ground for your sake;
>   In toil you shall eat of it All the days of your life." (Gen 3:17 NKJ)

And

> Gen 3:23 therefore the LORD God sent him out of the garden of Eden to
>   till the ground from which he was taken. (Gen 3:23 NKJ)

Consider that until after the flood there is no instruction to eat meat (Gen 9:2). These are not prohibitions against keeping any livestock but commands about how he must sustain himself.

Also remember God has already brought the animal kingdom under the care of man (Gen 2:19-20) so mankind has a responsibility to care for the animal world, and man must work to produce the fruits of the earth for food these are not contradictory commands and Abel is not in disobedience for his focus ont he animal world.